# How to Capture Game Score in Realtime - OpenCV and Pytesseract

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, python-tesseract

I want to capture the score and timer from a game being played on the PC full screen in real-time, I have working code below, however it will only recognize the scores '0' or timer '1:13' when separately cropped but not '0 1:13 0' from the full cropped image which is what I want. The code produces '45' from the full image which is weird (may be misrecognizing due to the line graphics in the image?), however I want the result to be '0 1:13 0', help!

How do I remove the graphics in the full image so there is only text as I think this is why it is not returning 0 1:13 0 or is there another reason?

[image: Link to Score Full Image Here]
[image: Link to Score Full Image Here]

Code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

from PIL import ImageGrab
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

while True:
    cap1 = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(740, 260, 1070,300)).convert('L') 
    cap = ImageOps.invert(cap1)

    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(cap,lang='eng', config='--psm 10 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789:')

    text = text.strip()

    if len(text) > 0:
        print(text)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Updated Code merged in from the answer below (Please review any help welcome as I am a beginner and getting error): img = cv2.imread(cap)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Can't convert object to 'str' for 'filename':

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8

import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import ImageGrab

while True:

    cap = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(740, 260, 1070,300))

    # Read Image and Crop Borders
    img = cv2.imread(cap)

    # Gray Color
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    binary = gray.copy()

    # Thresholding
    th1 = 20
    th2 = 200
    binary[binary<th1]=0
    binary[binary>th2]=0
    binary[binary>=th1]=255

    # Resize as original image is small 
    scale_ = 5 # of original size
    width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_ )
    height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_ )
    dim = (width, height)
    # resize image
    resized = cv2.resize(binary, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    # Filtering
    filtered = cv2.medianBlur(resized, 17)

    # Morhpology
    # res = cv2.erode(resized, None)

    # IMG Dimensions
    h, w = filtered.shape[:2]

    # Cropping
    s1 = filtered[:,:w//3]
    s2 = filtered[:,2*w//3:]
    t = filtered[:,w//3:2*w//3]

    for i in [s1, t, s2]:
        # OCR
        print(pytesseract.image_to_string(i,  lang='eng',config='--psm 7'))

    # Visualization
    disp = cv2.cvtColor(filtered, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    disp[:, w//3] = (0, 0, 255)
    disp[:, 2*w//3] = (0, 0, 255)

    cv2.namedWindow("output", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow("output", disp)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a classical processing before OCR as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/s/75978925) in addition to medianFiltering to remove salt & paper noise, then split your image into three thirds to detect each seperately:

> output `0` `1:13` `0`
> [image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8

import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

im_path="./"
im_name = "2.jpg"

# Read Image and Crop Borders
img = cv2.imread(im_path+im_name)

# Gray Color
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

binary = gray.copy()

# Thresholding
th1 = 20
th2 = 200
binary[binary<th1]=0
binary[binary>th2]=0
binary[binary>=th1]=255

# Resize as original image is small 
scale_ = 5 # of original size
width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_ )
height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_ )
dim = (width, height)
# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(binary, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# Filtering
filtered = cv2.medianBlur(resized, 17)

# Morhpology
# res = cv2.erode(resized, None)

# IMG Dimensions
h, w = filtered.shape[:2]

# Cropping
s1 = filtered[:,:w//3]
s2 = filtered[:,2*w//3:]
t = filtered[:,w//3:2*w//3]

for i in [s1, t, s2]:
    # OCR
    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(i,  lang='eng',config='--psm 7'))

# Visualization
disp = cv2.cvtColor(filtered, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

disp[:, w//3] = (0, 0, 255)
disp[:, 2*w//3] = (0, 0, 255)

cv2.namedWindow("output", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("output", disp)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: thanks for the example can you help as I am a beginner and do not know how to merge my code above into yours. The image is coming from screen capture ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(740, 260, 1070,300)) not a directory can post the combined code, this will be good to learn from.

Comment: @Crazyfrog just replace `img` in my code with `cap` from your code.

Comment: I am sorry I am beginner and spent 2 hours trying to merge but I have no idea. I will post what I have above.

Comment: Really appreciate your help with this. When code merged would it be possible to put the result in one variable on one line '0 1:13 0' as at present your code puts each on separate line.